# How much support is there for -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch

Tags: android, css, ios5, webkit, scroll

How many browsers support

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch
```

iOS5 does, what about the rest of them, and android etc..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of this writing, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` was exclusive to Mobile Safari on iOS 5 and later.

As of mid-2012, the latest Android version (4.1 Jelly Bean) does not support it, but it IS supported in Chrome for Android, which can be downloaded from Google Play (and only supports Android 4.0+). Android 3.0+ supports overflow: scroll, but it's not very snappy.

Comment: Does anyone have a specific version number for Android support? I'm not seeing in ICS...

Comment: Does anyone know if it's supported in any of the 2.3 builds?

Comment: It is currently NOT supported on the default Android browser (not even in the latest version, 4.1 jelly bean). However, it IS supported in Chrome for Android, which you can download from Google Play. This means that you cannot use webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch in PhoneGap apps, and for most other use cases at this time. Instead you can use overflow: scroll, but that's only supported in Android 3.0+, so use iScroll, or the many other alternatives out there.

Answer (score 3):

Just iOS5 right now. The only other major mobile browser that would use this would be Chrome as others have their own extensions.

Comment: Is there something like a -ms and a -moz version of this then

Comment: I believe Mobile IE supports it already. Firefox Beta for Android supports overflow:scroll. http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/7.0.1/releasenotes/

Comment: `overflow: scroll` is not the same as `overflow-scrolling: touch`. The former dictates how a box should be displayed with overflowing content; the latter dictates how the user interacts with the overflowing content (according to Apple anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Since this post is now 2 years old, just thought I'd share some helpful updates I dug up:

[Chrome Browser for Android no longer supports -webkit-overflow-scrolling? Is there an alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906508/chrome-browser-for-android-no-longer-supports-webkit-overflow-scrolling-is-the)

http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Android 4.1.2 Stock Browser that comes with the Galaxy S2 official firmware reports that it supports webkit-overflow-scrolling, but when you poll the value, it's always an empty string.

Which can lead to nasty bugs like this one: https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce/issues/8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I tried adding a comment to the accepted answer, to improve it, but as you noted SO would not let me because I was on a throwaway account (like usual). Sorry, but since I only answer one or two questions a year, I don't want to create a proper account. Hopefully I provided some useful information by creating a new answer, although it's not the preferred way to do things on SO. Not sure why comments on other people's answers need to be disallowed in the first place (while allowing to post an new answer, which is much more visible...)