# Phonegap and Android Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, overflow

I am deploying application with Phonegap for Android and iPhone.

I am using style ->  Overflow : scroll for Scrolling contents.

Its working properly in iPhone Application. Even working on Android Applications for version 3.0 and later versions.

But Facing Issue : The entire page scrolls up/down instead of the specific scroller of data in older versions like 2.1 & 2.2

Any Solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use iScroll for this purpose,for getting this script you can look at this [link](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).  iScroll4 supports iPhone/Ipod touch (>=3.1.1) iPad ( >=3.2)  , Android ( >=1.6) , Desktop Webkit, Firefox, Opera desktop/mobile etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Android and iPhone devices in older versions did not support Overflow at all, or in limited instances, so the only way to overcome this would be to involve some JavaScript, just as jQuery Mobile did in their previous versions

also, maybe check this: [How much support is there for -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768363/how-much-support-is-there-for-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch)