# Vertical scroll issue in Android OS

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Phonegap and Android Scrolling Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089096/phonegap-and-android-scrolling-issue)

I am using Phonegap for Android/iOS app development. In my index.html I have a header div and a footer div and in between them the div for content. I am giving following style for the content (middle) div:

```
<div id="edit" title="Edit" style="top:10%;height:80%;overflow:scroll"></div>
```

So if content exceeds available space, the content should scroll vertically keeping header and footer intact/fixed. But the content doesn't slide in Android OS. It is coming fixed only. The same thing worked fine for iOS. How can I establish this in Android?

Comment: Can you post your complete html / css code? maybe create a http://jsfiddle.net with it?

Comment: Check my answer for a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12089521/1276002 "Phonegap and Android Scrolling Issue").

Comment: iscroll plugin is not working in android 2.3. How should i go about doing it in 2.3

Comment: clint, are you using iscroll or iscroll4? for me iScroll4 was working fine on 2.3.

Comment: If anybody can suggest anything apart from iscroll4, i will try that as i have tried icroll4 in totality and its not working. I am using android 2.3.

Comment: If u can suggest anything apart from iscroll4, i will try that as i have tried iscroll4 in totality and its not working for my code. I am using android 2.3.