# Chrome Browser for Android no longer supports -webkit-overflow-scrolling? Is there an alternative?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit, scroll, overflow

I updated to the newest version of Chrome for Android on my Nexus 7 tablet and ...

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

... no longer works. In addition, the following evaluates to false:

```
!!('WebkitOverflowScrolling' in document.documentElement.style)
```

Was support for overflow scrolling removed from more recent builds of Chrome for Android? Is there an equivalent or comparable alternative momentum scrolling mechanism (not iScroll, etc.) that I can use found in the newest version?

As well, I searched for Chrome Beta in the Play Store on my device and it does not come up in the search results. Maybe the beta version is not offered for Nexus 7 tablets?

Any help on this matter is much appreciated. It's very frustrating that Google appears to have removed this feature from their browser ....

***edit:***

**Detailed version information:**

Nexus 7 tablet running Android version 4.2.2

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

and

```
!!('WebkitOverflowScrolling' in document.documentElement.style)
```

- Works and evaluates to true on Chrome version 18.0.1025469
- Does not work and evaluates to false on Chrome version 26.0.1410.58

Comment: Can you please provide exact Android OS version, and exact Chrome for Android version ? Thanks.

Comment: @mastDrinkNimbuPani, thank you for your response. The original post was edited with your requested information added.

Comment: Why would you need to coerce the value with `!!` when it is already a `boolean`...

Answer (score 18):

Try adding `z-index: 0` to the element with `overflow: scroll` to create a stacking-context that provides a hint to Chrome to use the fast-scrolling code path.

**Background:**

I am currently experiencing this issue after updating to the latest version of Chrome for Android. This was also compounded for me by the fact that due to this change the [current Modernizr test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/overflow-scrolling.js) for this feature now returns false, so my CSS styles were not being applied.

Digging around I found another [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128325#c23) that discusses the support for overflow scrolling touch:

> Tien-Ren observed while debugging 162363 that -webkit-overflow-touch
>   is an inherited property.  So the behavior of setting `z-index: 0` on all
>   non-hidden elements with that property creates a cascade of stacking
>   contexts below it.  (This behavior, behind
>   ENABLE_ACCELERATED_OVERFLOW_SCROLLING, is currently enabled only on
>   Android.)  **The obvious fix would be to set `z-index: 0` on only
>   "overflow: scroll" elements.**

So it would seem that if you are having issues with the scrolling not working as expected then adding `z-index: 0` to the element with overflow: scroll then this may help. However this did not work for me, although the scrolling sections worked (after I had modified the Modernizr css-overflow-scrolling test to return true for this version of Chrome) the momentum effect of the scrolling was not present.

Comment: z-index: 0 worked perfectly for me. Had the hardest time solving this. Thank you!

Comment: I am still having serious issues with this one... is there any other kind of solution?

Comment: Works for me, but as said, only with Android KitKat. Using iOS or older Android versions it results in scrolling without momentum. So not really usable for a webapp. :(

Comment: z-index didn't work for me. But -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) did the trick. This is a serious hack, but just in case if someone faces issue with this.

Comment: And what about modal windows? I'm inside one, with z-index of 1002, and I can't reduce it.

Answer (score 8):

From this URL = https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175670&q=overflow-scrolling&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

'
No, I think this was indeed triggered by 172481. **We removed -webkit-overflow-scrolling with the hopes that it was no longer necessary because we'd automatically opt-in to fast scrolling when we need. The problem is that it isn't happening here.**

Those SP changes you mentioned probably won't affect this issue because they won't show up on a non-corp account, right? I think everything works fine with corp but I'll check.
'

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still not getting why -webkit-overflow-scrolling would be "no longer necessary." What is "fast scrolling?" I'm guessing it is only relevant for the particular context being discussed in the page linked above and not for general purposes.

So there really isn't a non-plugin alternative to standard **overflow: auto** functionality? Because **overflow: auto** predictably gives low quality scrolling with no momentum.

Comment: "fast scrolling" is native accelerated scrolling. The point is that -webkit-overflow-scrolling is useless as it should be the default behaviour of overflow: scroll. That is what they wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

A dirty solution that worked for me (required Hammer js):

```
  Hammer($('body')[0]).on("dragup", function(ev) {
            window.scrollBy(0,ev.gesture.distance);
        });
         Hammer($('body')[0]).on("dragdown", function(ev) {
            window.scrollBy(0,-ev.gesture.distance);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

we had scroll problems with on Chrome 40.0... on Android (tablet & mobile) and we fixed with css only solution. Maybe it is not clean but works for us:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
html, body {
    z-index: 0 !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    }
}
```