# CSS autohide scrollbar when not scrolling on Android webpage

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Is there a way to make the scrollbar auto-hide when a user is not scrolling a webpage on an Android device, but make it visible when it is scrolling?

Please note that Firefox browsers does have this behaviour enabled by default, it's just Chrome and stock(Samsung, HTC) browsers that don't.

This is what I currently have:

```
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

And I can always see the scrollbar on the list (except in ffox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, I found this question on stackoverflow:
[Overflow:scroll elements on android and native scrolling, -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247374/overflowscroll-elements-on-android-and-native-scrolling-webkit-overflow-scrol)

So, using `-webkit-transform: translatez(0)` will enable the scroll bar to auto-hide when not scrolling.

Comment: I have tried this on older android phones, on stock browser (4.1.2), and I get no scroll bar at all....