# Javascript - setting -webkit-overflow-scrolling css property to body through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply the css property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` to the body of the document through javascript. I googled around and found different ways. So far I have tried the following:

```
document.body.style.WebkitOverflowScrolling = 'touch'
document.body.style.webkitOverflowScrolling = 'touch'
document.body.style['-webkit-overflow-scrolling']= 'touch'
```

I tried in the Chrome & Safari console, unfortunately none of the above seems to be working specifically for `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` css property. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: doesn't seems to be supported by most of browsers [`webkit-overflow-scrolling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @CodeManiac I also tried in Safari but still no luck. It works in most of the browsers when applying through css

Comment: As @CodeManiac wrote this is not a standard css you can try this solution [chrome-browser-for-android-no-longer-supports-webkit-overflow-scrolling-is-the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906508/chrome-browser-for-android-no-longer-supports-webkit-overflow-scrolling-is-the)