# CSS: horizontal scroll in mobile navigation

Tags: css

This is a mobile version of my website.

[image: mobile version of my website]

I want to make the sub-nav(Main|Another Long Category|) be able to scroll horizontally. People could touch the screen and scroll(Rather than using scroll bars like what we have in desktop browsers).

How to do it? I don't know what's effect's name, hence don't know how to describe it properly.

UPDATE:
[image]
I add `overflow-x` to it. But it stacks up rather than span into a single line.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, you need to calculate total width of your menu elements using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var menuWidth=0;
    $('.wrapper a').map(function(){
        menuWidth = menuWidth + $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    // + 15px to fix, this maybe vary in your project
    $('.wrapper').css('width', (menuWidth+15)); 
});
```

On the container CSS class you need to add:

```
.subnav{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HhHGH/

**Basic CSS scrolling**

Just add `overflow:scroll` to your CSS nav class or the fancy way:

**Fancy CSS scrolling on iOS**

You can try using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` in your CSS nav class.

This works pretty well on iOS, for another devices check this questions:

[How much support is there for -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768363/how-much-support-is-there-for-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch)

[Chrome Browser for Android no longer supports -webkit-overflow-scrolling? Is there an alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906508/chrome-browser-for-android-no-longer-supports-webkit-overflow-scrolling-is-the)

Comment: I get a problem now.... The nav pills just stack up together. Is there any example I can see?

Comment: If you provide [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) More than happy to assist further.

Comment: The additional stack problem solved now. I make a wrapper inside the nav and give it a width 150% to hack into.

Comment: The problem now is that, the first solution is not support that much. (The mobile browser situation is very complex in my country). Should I make it with javascript? but how?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle to start prototyping?

Comment: @EduLomeli, listentome.herokuapp.com. account&pw: test@example.com

Comment: Is it possible to use http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/carousel.html this?

Comment: yes you can, is more complex but you can get something cool, check [this example](http://codepen.io/leison/pen/fsmEh) and the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906508/chrome-browser-for-android-no-longer-supports-webkit-overflow-scrolling-is-the)