# difficulty in showing scroll-bar on android device for cross-platform app

Tags: android, html, angularjs, css, cross-platform

I am working on a cross-platform application developed using `html5`, `css3` and `angularJS`. 
I am facing an issue in showing the `ScrollBar` on android device.

I have used  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

It is working fine on iPAD but its has no effect on android device.
Need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version for android?

Comment: @Ramesh Android version 4.0+

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly said, Android native WebView does not "show" a scroll bar when using `overflow:scroll|auto`. But the scrolling is allowed when you touch and move the container around. So scroll should still work as expected, without the bouncy effect.

Another Android catch is till 4.4, the native WebView is not the one used in Chrome, i.e. ChromeView. So you are going to have to deal with it by using a javascript polyfill, like overthrow.js [http://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow/] or iscroll. Personally, iscroll ux sucks on Samsung Galaxy Tabs.

But if you are targetting Android 4.0>=, then this might help https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview. Haven't personally tried it though.

Check out for more details on webview changes https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

> Android 4.4 (KitKat) includes a new WebView component based on the Chromium open source project. ...[truncated]...., so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.

Comment: Any way-around to display scrollbars for Samsung Galaxy - Android devices ?

Answer (score 0):

> As of this writing, -webkit-overflow-scrolling was exclusive to Mobile Safari on iOS 5 and later.
>
> As of mid-2012, the latest Android version (4.1 Jelly Bean) does not support it, but it IS supported in Chrome for Android, which can be downloaded from Google Play (and only supports Android 4.0+). Android 3.0+ supports overflow: scroll, but it's not very snappy.

Referred from : [How much support is there for -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768363/how-much-support-is-there-for-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch)

Comment: Is there any way to show scroll-bar in android application. As i have already tried overflow:scroll which didn't work.

Comment: @tanuj Have you got this resolved? I am also facing similar issue, so.